# Having problems getting my variables passed into the database when form is submitted

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have 3 php files.  The first dispatch.php creates a form with a dropdown selection of employees(variable that must be passed through) you must choose from and displays dispatch2.php with rows of data.  The first column of each row is a checkbox that = order number(a variable that must be passed through). The second column dipslays that order number. Then we have additional columns one is age of order.  This column takes order time(a variable to be passed) and calculates age(a variable to be passed).  So you choose employee, the appropriate checkboxes and click submit.

Dispatch.php and dispatch2.php display fine.  When I click submit I get an error. So instead of writing to the database I echoed the variable and didn't get any. the only thing that it displayed was the non variable OTD.

here is the dispatch_post.php with just echos of the variables.

```
<?php
echo $orders->fields['order_id'];
echo $orders->fields['date_purchased'];
echo $result->fields['employee_id'];
echo $difference;
echo 'OTD';
?>
```

"OTD" should be written to the status column in the table whenever the form is submitted and therefore I didn't change it to a variable.  If I should let me know.

This is my first form that I have made.  So I apologize if this is simple and I haven't seen the mistake.

Here are my files.
dispatch.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * @package admin
 * @copyright Copyright 2003-2013 Zen Cart Development Team
 * @copyright Portions Copyright 2003 osCommerce
 * @license http://www.zen-cart.com/license/2_0.txt GNU Public License V2.0
 * @version GIT: $Id: Author: DrByte  Wed Nov 6 21:04:33 2013 -0500 Modified in v1.5.2 $
 */

  require('includes/application_top.php');

  // unset variable which is sometimes tainted by bad plugins like magneticOne tools
  if (isset($module)) unset($module);

  require(DIR_WS_CLASSES . 'currencies.php');
  $currencies = new currencies();

  if (isset($_GET['oID'])) $_GET['oID'] = (int)$_GET['oID'];

  include(DIR_WS_CLASSES . 'order.php');

?>
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html <?php echo HTML_PARAMS; ?>>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php echo CHARSET; ?>">
<title><?php echo TITLE; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/dispatch.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // load text file when page loads
      $("#div1").load("https://secure3243.hostgator.com/~w57dsjmm/order/ducky/dispatch2.php");

      // Then reload it every 5 seconds, for ever ...
      setInterval(function(){
        $("#div1").load("https://secure3243.hostgator.com/~w57dsjmm/order/ducky/dispatch2.php");
      }, 5000);
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init()">
<!-- header_eof //-->
<!-- body //-->
<!-- body_text //-->
<p><a href="http://order.southshorepizza.net/ducky">ADMIN</A>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
Dispatch Screen</p>
<form action="dispatch_post.php" method="post">
<div class="dropdown" valign="center">
<select required name="dropdown">
<option value="Select Driver" selected>Select Driver</option>
<?php
$result = $db->Execute("SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_EMPLOYEES);
while (!$result->EOF) {
  echo '<option value="' . $result->fields['employee_id'] . '">' . $result->fields['employee_first'] . '</option>';
$result->MoveNext(); 
  }
?>
</select>
</div>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
    <tr class="dataTableHeadingRow">
         <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" width="10%" align="center"><?php echo "Dispatch"; ?></td>
         <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" width="20%" align="center"><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_ORDERS_ID; ?></td>
         <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" width="30%" align="center"><?php echo "Address"; ?></td>
         <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" width="20%" align="center"><?php echo "Order Age"; ?></td>
         <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" width="20%" align="center"><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_ORDER_TOTAL; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="div1">
</div>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
<!-- body_eof //-->
</body>
```

dispatch2.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @package admin
 * @copyright Copyright 2003-2013 Zen Cart Development Team
 * @copyright Portions Copyright 2003 osCommerce
 * @license http://www.zen-cart.com/license/2_0.txt GNU Public License V2.0
 * @version GIT: $Id: Author: DrByte  Wed Nov 6 21:04:33 2013 -0500 Modified in v1.5.2 $
 */

  require('includes/application_top.php');

  // unset variable which is sometimes tainted by bad plugins like magneticOne tools
  if (isset($module)) unset($module);

  require(DIR_WS_CLASSES . 'currencies.php');
  $currencies = new currencies();

  if (isset($_GET['oID'])) $_GET['oID'] = (int)$_GET['oID'];

  include(DIR_WS_CLASSES . 'order.php');

?>
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html <?php echo HTML_PARAMS; ?>>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php echo CHARSET; ?>">
<title><?php echo TITLE; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/dispatch.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/cssjsmenuhover.css" media="all" id="hoverJS">
</head>
<body onLoad="init()">
<!-- body //-->
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<!-- body_text //-->
<tr>
<?php
 $new_fields = ", o.delivery_street_address, o.shipping_module_code ";

      $orders_query_raw = "select " . $search_distinct . " o.orders_id, o.customers_id, o.customers_name, o.payment_method, o.shipping_method, o.date_purchased, o.last_modified, o.currency, o.currency_value, s.orders_status_name, ot.text as order_total" .
                          $new_fields . "
                          from (" . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS . " s, " .
                          TABLE_ORDERS . " o " .
                          $new_table . ")
                          left join " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " ot on (o.orders_id = ot.orders_id and ot.class = 'ot_total') " . "
                          where (o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id and s.language_id = '" . (int)$_SESSION['languages_id'] . "' and o.shipping_module_code LIKE 'Flat' AND orders_status <> 3)  " .
                          $search . " order by o.orders_id DESC";

//echo '<BR><BR>I SEE C: ' . $orders_query_raw . '<BR><BR>';

    //last edit before $orders_query_raw }

// Split Page
// reset page when page is unknown
if (($_GET['page'] == '' or $_GET['page'] <= 1) and $_GET['oID'] != '') {
  $check_page = $db->Execute($orders_query_raw);
  $check_count=1;
  if ($check_page->RecordCount() > '15') {
    while (!$check_page->EOF) {
      if ($check_page->fields['orders_id'] == $_GET['oID']) {
        break;
      }
      $check_count++;
      $check_page->MoveNext();
    }
    $_GET['page'] = round((($check_count/'15')+(fmod_round($check_count,'15') !=0 ? .5 : 0)),0);
  } else {
    $_GET['page'] = 1;
  }
}

//    $orders_query_numrows = '';
    $orders_split = new splitPageResults($_GET['page'], '15', $orders_query_raw, $orders_query_numrows);
    $orders = $db->Execute($orders_query_raw);
    while (!$orders->EOF) {
    if ((!isset($_GET['oID']) || (isset($_GET['oID']) && ($_GET['oID'] == $orders->fields['orders_id']))) && !isset($oInfo)) {
        $oInfo = new objectInfo($orders->fields);
      }


?>
<div id="div1">
      <td class="dataTableContent" width="10%" align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="otd" value="$orders->fields['orders_id']" /></td>
      <td class="dataTableContent" width="20%" align="center"><?php echo $show_difference . $orders->fields['orders_id']; ?></td>
      <td class="dataTableContent" width="30%" align="center"><?php echo $orders->fields['delivery_street_address']; ?></td>
      <td class="dataTableContent" width="20%" align="center"><?php
$purchase_time = strtotime ($orders->fields['date_purchased']);
$difference = time () - $purchase_time;
$difference_in_minutes = ceil ($difference / 60);  //-Round up to the next minute
echo gmdate("H:i:s", $difference);  
?></td>
      <td class="dataTableContent" width="20%" align="center"><?php echo strip_tags($orders->fields['order_total']); ?></td></div>
 </tr>
<?php
      $orders->MoveNext();
    }
?>
 <tr>
     <td class="smallText" valign="top" colspan="2"><?php echo $orders_split->display_count($orders_query_numrows, '15', $_GET['page'], TEXT_DISPLAY_NUMBER_OF_ORDERS); ?></td>
     <td class="smallText" align="left"><?php echo $orders_split->display_links($orders_query_numrows, '15', MAX_DISPLAY_PAGE_LINKS, $_GET['page'], zen_get_all_get_params(array('page', 'oID', 'action'))); ?></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
<!-- body_text_eof //-->
<!-- body_eof //-->
</body>
</html>
<?php require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'application_bottom.php'); ?>
```

and finally dispatch_post.php

```
<?php
<?php
global $db;
$otd = "otd";
$sql = "insert into " . TABLE_HTA . " (order_id, order_time, employee_id, otd, status) values (:$orders->fields['order_id']:, :$orders->fields['date_purchased']:, :$result->fields['employee_id']:, :$difference:, :'OTD':)";

$sql = $db->bindVars($sql, ':$orders->fields['order_id']:', $valueOne, 'integer');
$sql = $db->bindVars($sql, ':$orders->fields['date_purchased']:', $valueTwo, 'time');
$sql = $db->bindVars($sql, ':$result->fields['employee_id']:', $valueThree, 'integer');
$sql = $db->bindVars($sql, ':$difference:', $valueFour, 'time');
$sql = $db->bindVars($sql, ':$difference:', $valuefive, 'varchar');
$result = $db->Execute($sql);
$newRecordId = $db->Insert_ID();
echo 'The new record added was number: ' . $newRecordId;
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Errors, if any? Checking for them? If not, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, plus depending on the API you're using, use/add `or die(mysqli_error($DB_connection))` to `mysqli_query()` or equivalent.

Comment: Probably not your issue; however, it looks like you are loading dispatch2.php into #div1. Dispatch2.php also includes a #div1 which would give you two divs with the id div1?

Comment: If you are loading dispatch2 into dispatch, do you need the second html formatting? i.e. do you need the <html><head></head><body></body></html> in the second file or will that mess up your code?

Comment: Error reporting isn't giving me additional details.  The variable isn't being passed so it can't be written.   I missed that div1 in the dispatch2.php.  I have corrected that.  Thank you.   As far as the second html formatting I'm not sure.  As stated this is my first attempt at a form with php. It's also my first time using AJAX to refresh a division.

Answer (score 0):

I think the load of html information in both the first and second may mess you up. Try this:

*- my comments are noted by nwolybug*

dispatch.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @package admin
 * @copyright Copyright 2003-2013 Zen Cart Development Team
 * @copyright Portions Copyright 2003 osCommerce
 * @license http://www.zen-cart.com/license/2_0.txt GNU Public License V2.0
 * @version GIT: $Id: Author: DrByte  Wed Nov 6 21:04:33 2013 -0500 Modified in v1.5.2 $
 */

  require('includes/application_top.php');

  // unset variable which is sometimes tainted by bad plugins like magneticOne tools
  if (isset($module)) unset($module);

  require(DIR_WS_CLASSES . 'currencies.php');
  $currencies = new currencies();

  if (isset($_GET['oID'])) $_GET['oID'] = (int)$_GET['oID'];

  include(DIR_WS_CLASSES . 'order.php');

?>
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html <?php echo HTML_PARAMS; ?>>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php echo CHARSET; ?>">
<title><?php echo TITLE; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/dispatch.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // load text file when page loads
      $("#div1").load("https://secure3243.hostgator.com/~w57dsjmm/order/ducky/dispatch2.php");

      // Then reload it every 5 seconds, for ever ...
      setInterval(function(){
        $("#div1").load("https://secure3243.hostgator.com/~w57dsjmm/order/ducky/dispatch2.php");
      }, 5000);
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init()">
<!-- header_eof //-->
<!-- body //-->
<!-- body_text //-->
<p><a href="http://order.southshorepizza.net/ducky">ADMIN</A>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
Dispatch Screen</p>
<form action="dispatch_post.php" method="post">
  <div class="dropdown" valign="center">
    <select required name="dropdown">
      <option value="Select Driver" selected>Select Driver</option>
      <?php
      $result = $db->Execute("SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_EMPLOYEES);
      while (!$result->EOF) {
        echo '<option value="' . $result->fields['employee_id'] . '">' . $result->fields['employee_first'] . '</option>';
      $result->MoveNext(); 
        }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
      <tr class="dataTableHeadingRow">
           <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" width="10%" align="center"><?php echo "Dispatch"; ?></td>
           <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" width="20%" align="center"><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_ORDERS_ID; ?></td>
           <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" width="30%" align="center"><?php echo "Address"; ?></td>
           <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" width="20%" align="center"><?php echo "Order Age"; ?></td>
           <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" width="20%" align="center"><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_ORDER_TOTAL; ?></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="div1">
  </div>

  <!--nwolybug added / to end the input -->
  <input type="submit" /> 
</form>
</div>
```

dispatch2.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @package admin
 * @copyright Copyright 2003-2013 Zen Cart Development Team
 * @copyright Portions Copyright 2003 osCommerce
 * @license http://www.zen-cart.com/license/2_0.txt GNU Public License V2.0
 * @version GIT: $Id: Author: DrByte  Wed Nov 6 21:04:33 2013 -0500 Modified in v1.5.2 $
 */

  require('includes/application_top.php');

  // unset variable which is sometimes tainted by bad plugins like magneticOne tools
  if (isset($module)) unset($module);

  require(DIR_WS_CLASSES . 'currencies.php');
  $currencies = new currencies();

  if (isset($_GET['oID'])) $_GET['oID'] = (int)$_GET['oID'];

  include(DIR_WS_CLASSES . 'order.php');

?>


<!--nwolybug removed head and body tags, moved formatting to dispatch.php head -->

<!-- body //-->
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<!-- body_text //-->
<tr>
<?php
 $new_fields = ", o.delivery_street_address, o.shipping_module_code ";

      $orders_query_raw = "select " . $search_distinct . " o.orders_id, o.customers_id, o.customers_name, o.payment_method, o.shipping_method, o.date_purchased, o.last_modified, o.currency, o.currency_value, s.orders_status_name, ot.text as order_total" .
                          $new_fields . "
                          from (" . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS . " s, " .
                          TABLE_ORDERS . " o " .
                          $new_table . ")
                          left join " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " ot on (o.orders_id = ot.orders_id and ot.class = 'ot_total') " . "
                          where (o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id and s.language_id = '" . (int)$_SESSION['languages_id'] . "' and o.shipping_module_code LIKE 'Flat' AND orders_status <> 3)  " .
                          $search . " order by o.orders_id DESC";

//echo '<BR><BR>I SEE C: ' . $orders_query_raw . '<BR><BR>';

    //last edit before $orders_query_raw }

// Split Page
// reset page when page is unknown
if (($_GET['page'] == '' or $_GET['page'] <= 1) and $_GET['oID'] != '') {
  $check_page = $db->Execute($orders_query_raw);
  $check_count=1;
  if ($check_page->RecordCount() > '15') {
    while (!$check_page->EOF) {
      if ($check_page->fields['orders_id'] == $_GET['oID']) {
        break;
      }
      $check_count++;
      $check_page->MoveNext();
    }
    $_GET['page'] = round((($check_count/'15')+(fmod_round($check_count,'15') !=0 ? .5 : 0)),0);
  } else {
    $_GET['page'] = 1;
  }
}

//    $orders_query_numrows = '';
    $orders_split = new splitPageResults($_GET['page'], '15', $orders_query_raw, $orders_query_numrows);
    $orders = $db->Execute($orders_query_raw);
    while (!$orders->EOF) {
    if ((!isset($_GET['oID']) || (isset($_GET['oID']) && ($_GET['oID'] == $orders->fields['orders_id']))) && !isset($oInfo)) {
        $oInfo = new objectInfo($orders->fields);
      }


?>

<!--nwolybug changed div1 to div2 for naming standards. can't have two divs with same id name -->
<div id="div2">
      <td class="dataTableContent" width="10%" align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="otd" value="$orders->fields['orders_id']" /></td>
      <td class="dataTableContent" width="20%" align="center"><?php echo $show_difference . $orders->fields['orders_id']; ?></td>
      <td class="dataTableContent" width="30%" align="center"><?php echo $orders->fields['delivery_street_address']; ?></td>
      <td class="dataTableContent" width="20%" align="center"><?php
$purchase_time = strtotime ($orders->fields['date_purchased']);
$difference = time () - $purchase_time;
$difference_in_minutes = ceil ($difference / 60);  //-Round up to the next minute
echo gmdate("H:i:s", $difference);  
?></td>
      <td class="dataTableContent" width="20%" align="center"><?php echo strip_tags($orders->fields['order_total']); ?></td></div>
 </tr>
<?php
      $orders->MoveNext();
    }
?>
 <tr>
     <td class="smallText" valign="top" colspan="2"><?php echo $orders_split->display_count($orders_query_numrows, '15', $_GET['page'], TEXT_DISPLAY_NUMBER_OF_ORDERS); ?></td>
     <td class="smallText" align="left"><?php echo $orders_split->display_links($orders_query_numrows, '15', MAX_DISPLAY_PAGE_LINKS, $_GET['page'], zen_get_all_get_params(array('page', 'oID', 'action'))); ?></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

dispatch_post.php

```
<?php
//nwolybug removed first of two <?php tags

global $db;
$otd = "otd";
$sql = "insert into " . TABLE_HTA . " (order_id, order_time, employee_id, otd, status) values (:$orders->fields['order_id']:, :$orders->fields['date_purchased']:, :$result->fields['employee_id']:, :$difference:, :'OTD':)";

$sql = $db->bindVars($sql, ':$orders->fields['order_id']:', $valueOne, 'integer');
$sql = $db->bindVars($sql, ':$orders->fields['date_purchased']:', $valueTwo, 'time');
$sql = $db->bindVars($sql, ':$result->fields['employee_id']:', $valueThree, 'integer');
$sql = $db->bindVars($sql, ':$difference:', $valueFour, 'time');
$sql = $db->bindVars($sql, ':$difference:', $valuefive, 'varchar');
$result = $db->Execute($sql);
$newRecordId = $db->Insert_ID();
echo 'The new record added was number: ' . $newRecordId;
?>
```

Comment: it still cannot echo the variables on submit. :(

Comment: Without access to the code, it is difficult to figure out the problem. I usually like to run it on my system, but don't have all the includes or general database entries... Do you get any errors? Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: I do have error strict error reporting enabled. It's zen-cart if you have that.  I created a table called hta.   If you can help me get to the point I can echo the variables on the dispatch_post.php file that would be awesome.  I think I can get it from there.  I just have no idea why it displays the correct info but doesn't pass the info when submit is clicked.

Comment: I am creating a virtualbox environment now to see if I can help further. May be a bit to get things running, but hopefully I can help. Will keep you updated on progress.

Comment: Thank you.  hta table has the following columns- order_id(11 integers), order_time(datetime), status(varchar 12), make_time(time), otd_time(time), delivery_time(time), employee_id(11 integer).  I made order_time(datetime) because that is what zen uses and figured it'd be easier to pass the variable as is instead of stripping the date from it.